# Dspace dual write to RDBMS and SOLR vs concurrency

Tags: database, solr, dspace

I'd like to know how dspace manage indexing in both the database and solr  while supporting concurrency. In other words, if 2 individuals try to write at the same time, on the same item (e.g. changing metadata), how do dspace ensure that the index will not be desynchronized with the database.

This can happen if USER1 write concurrently with USER 2 on the same metadata value, and the write to the database of USER 1 first happen, but then the Write to the database and the Index of USER2 happen, and then the write to the index of USER1 Happen.

In other words USER1 "write" will be in the index while User2 write will be in the database = inconsistency !!!

I wonder how this case can be avoid in dspace, which is a typical dual write problem.

With the Event system of dspace, i don't know how this can be avoided.

Does anyone knows?

[image]

Comment: Just as a note, your diagram is not accurate to how DSpace reindexes content in Solr. If we were to assume the *top* DB icon represented the DSpace database, and the *bottom* DB icon represents Solr, then you'd actually end up with:

 (1) Set X=A in DB
 (2) Set X=B in DB
 (3) Set X=B in Solr, as Solr index will see X=B in DB
 (4) Set X=B in Solr, as Solr index will see X=B in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solr, DSpace doesn't index just the single metadata change (when it occurs). It actually reindexes the entire Item in Solr.

What this means is that while concurrency is an issue in the Database layer (and writes/updates are synchronized in the database), it is not one in the Solr indexing process.

Here's what would/should happen in your example.

1. User 1 and User 2 edit the same Item's title at the same time.
2. The edits will be synchronized at the database level, so that the first one in happens first. Let's suppose User 1's edit happens first, then User 2's edit.
3. User 1's edit will trigger a reindex in Solr. So will User 2's edit. This means this same item will be reindexed twice (once for
   each edit). These reindexes are not tied to the specific update (so the first reindex doesn't only index the title), but just tell Solr that the item was updated and it needs reindexing.
4. On the first reindex, User 1's edit will have been made, so the Item will be indexed with that title
5. By the time of the second reindex, User 2's edit will have been made (as reindexes take longer in nature than saving an edit to the DB layer), so the Item will be (re-)indexed with that updated title.

So, the simple answer here is that DSpace doesn't reindex individual modifications (which could end up out of order if not synchronized with the DB edits). Instead, it tracks which objects have been updated and triggers a reindex of the entire object's metadata.  While this may seem like "overkill", the reindex of a single object in Solr is not all that process intensive, and it ensures that the object's current/latest metadata is indexed in Solr (in the case of simultaneous writes).

**UPDATE: As requested (in comments below), here's how DSpace performs reindexing (in Solr) in much more detail.**

1. DSpace has a defined Event system. It follows configurations in the `dspace.cfg` in this section: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L732
2. By default, in DSpace 5, the `IndexEventConsumer` is what performs indexing for Solr. It is defined configured by default here: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L732
3. In DSpace 5, whenever someone changes an Item's metadata (or anything about an Item), the [`Item.update()`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/Item.java#L1026) method is called to actually save the changes back to the database layer.
4. After saving all changes (using `DatabaseManager.update()`), the `Item.update()` method generates a [new MODIFY event in the Event System](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/Item.java#L1104).
5. That new MODIFY event is appended to the [LinkedList of events in the current Context](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/core/Context.java#L428)
6. When the [Context is committed](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/core/Context.java#L359) (which happens when saving a change), it first calls commit on the DB connection (ending the transaction). Then, it sends the list of events to the Dispatcher ([`BasicDispatcher`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/event/BasicDispatcher.java) is configured by default in dspace.cfg), which then in turn triggers the index in Solr (via the configured [`IndexEventConsumer`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/discovery/IndexEventConsumer.java))
7. The `IndexEventConsumer` passes the list of update objects (in this case an Item) to the IndexingService (`SolrServiceImpl` by default).
8. Finally, [`SolrServiceImpl.indexContent()`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/discovery/SolrServiceImpl.java#L206) reads the latest metadata value(s) from the Database and indexes them in Solr.

The above logic is still a bit simplified (as it'd be way too complex to walk through every step of the code).  But, the basic gist here is that each `Item.update()` call is treated as a database transaction. It also triggers the addition of a MODIFY event which is stored in the user's session (Context object). As soon as the DB transaction is committed, the MODIFY event is processed by the `IndexEventConsumer` which reindexes the *entire Item*.

So, in the case of simultaneous edits, two MODIFY events will be generated (one for each edit). However, the *last* MODIFY event will not be triggered until after the *last* database edit is committed.  Therefore, the Solr index should always be in sync with the latest info in the Database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Really appreciated. However, aside from your comment here, is there any documentation about that. I assumed it, based on my understanding of the old Event consumer documentation. What part of the architecture shall I read to back what you are explaining and understand it by myself. For instance this video in nuxeo cleary explaing what happens https://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/Elasticsearch+Indexing+Logic

Comment: The point is it is not clear to me the triggering mechanism. Does the re-indexing happen after a DB commit mechanism like in Nuxeo ? I thought it was happening in a consumer. In other words, writing in the DB happens in a consumer, as well as writing in the index. If both happens in a consumer, then we have a problem. If a solr consumer is activated only after a write to the database, then we are almost good as we still need to make sure that the reindex signal are stack up in the same order that the write to the DB happened.

Comment: I would really appreciate that you re-edit your answer, and explain the actual mechanism used. Not necessarily in detail, but at least enough for someone either to figure it out of your explanation, or go and dig in dspace doc or code to understand it.

Comment: Furthermore, what is not clear is your point 3. How do you ensure that solr indexing trigger of Edit1 happens before solr indexing trigger of edit2. This defies the logic of concurrency isn't it. Thread can stop and switch at any moment. I have re-edit my picture based on DB blog post on log based re-indexation superiority over dual write technics

Comment: I've updated my answer above with lots of code references / links. Hopefully it'll help answer all of your comments listed here.

Comment: Per your second comment above, both of these changes are NOT happening in a consumer (which I tried to clarify above). Only the Solr indexing happens in a consumer. The actual DB edit/save occurs using a database transaction. The Solr indexing is triggered only AFTER the database transaction is committed.

Comment: I think part of the confusion here may be that you are assuming DSpace treats the database and Solr equally and passes updates to them simultaneously. It doesn't.  In DSpace, the database is considered the "official record", while the Solr index is just a way of searching those official records. So, the Solr index is always updated *after* the database. You can even reindex your content in Solr (if for example you want to add more search options/facets).

Comment: Tim, your explanation is super clear now. I dig into the code a bit and with the help of the detail provided i get it. I also understand why you re-index the all item now. Basically If i understood well.

Comment: Basically, the method guarantee that for each update to the database, their will be an update in solr. Although the order is not guaranteed. After looking at the method in detail, what i see is that you can very well have a context switch within the context.commit. That is the operation connection.commit followed the dispatching of the event, is not an atomic operation. Hence you have to re-index the all item. If you were dealing with the detail of what has change, that could cause a problem, because the order would not be garantee. Am I correct here.

Comment: Tim now i get the all point of re-indexing the full item. Basically yes it is not a dual write, it is not a full log based solution either. You are just saying "hey something has changed" It does not matter if the first signal reach before the second (1st=A, 2nd=B), two re-index will happen anyway. It will re-read the all item and re-index. This method indeed can not guarantee the order, therefore it re-index everything.

Comment: Correct, this is exactly how DSpace treats reindexing content in Solr. Even if a small part of an item is changed, the entire item is reindexed.

Comment: Thank you guys for the details explanation